# Google Drive: Do editors, viewers receive a notification when authority removed?

Tags: google-drive, notifications, permissions

I'm going in and tidying up some permissions on Google documents I've created, mainly removing editors and viewers before archiving some documents.

Do the readers and viewers I remove received a notification that they have been "unfriended" from the document?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, unless they still have the document open in a tab. If it is open then they will get a notification that says that their permission settings have changed and it forces them to reload. If it is closed then they won't see it unless they go looking for that particular document and can't find it.

Comment: But any updates?

Answer (score 5):

I just tested this by sharing and then unsharing a Google Doc from my professional Google account to my personal, and while I received email notification that my personal account had been given access, I did *not* receive any notification of having had that access revoked when I unshared the document.

So no, just as in Facebook and Google+, people who have their access to a file on gDrive removed will not receive notification of being "unfriended."

Comment: But any updates?